# Mongo Query Performance Issue

Tags: arrays, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid

I am using mongodb with rails app. From past few days, I am facing weird issues while querying the data directly from mongodb. Let's say there is object M1 and this object has few parameters for which I need to query data from mongo. Now suppose I query data for current day, there are almost 5000 records, and I am using .to_a in rails controller, but this operation is taking almost 50~60 seconds. Now for same object M1 and for same as previous parameters, when I query data of any past day and use .to_a, it takes <10 seconds. Now again if I query for same object M1 and same parameters and use .to_a, it now takes <5 seconds. Also now if I change few of object parameters, it again take >50 seconds. And any query for historical data is taking <10 seconds but for current day is taking >50 seconds, unless I run that same query once for any past day. I have checked the indexes, and are being used correctly in each query. What can be possible reason for this?

Comment: Use https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-monitoring/#command-monitoring to identify whether the problem is in Mongoid or driver/database, update the question with findings.

Comment: Another thing to consider is using the MongoDB Database Profiler which will collect performance data for queries. Please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/